# Package Upgrade Fails After OS Upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade

An OS upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.6 by running `do-release-upgrade` seems to have had an error at some point as the packages can no longer be upgraded - we're seeing this error when running various commands:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-170-generic
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
```

Eg: running `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 152 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 39291 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (3.13.0-101.148) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_82eRAE/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_82eRAE/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Autoremove fails in the same way:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 152 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 39291 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (3.13.0-101.148) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_6lLSTG/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_6lLSTG/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and dpkg also has the problem:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.21) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-170-generic
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
```

Disk space seems to be ok:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            388M  4.0K  388M   1% /dev
tmpfs            81M  532K   81M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.8G  4.7G  3.6G  57% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            404M     0  404M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            81M     0   81M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Clean has done it's job:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

OS is

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

Is this a corruption in the kernel? Any steps that could be taken to salvage the server?

**Update**

As suggested I ran `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic` with the following results:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
(Reading database ... 39291 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (3.13.0-101.148) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_9Tbcam/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_9Tbcam/lib/modules/3.13.0-101-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
```

Comment: This looks like one of those very rare times that it's appropriate to use dpkg's `--force-remove` flag: Try `sudo dpkg --force-remove linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic`. If that fails, put on your heavy gloves and resort to the very-very rarely used nuclear option: dpkg's `--force-remove-reinstreq` flag: Try `sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic`. If *that* fails, please edit the question to include your complete output.

Comment: The first option fails:$ sudo dpkg --force-remove linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
dpkg: error: unknown force/refuse option 'remove'

Comment: $ dpkg --force-help
dpkg forcing options - control behaviour when problems found:
  warn but continue:  --force-<thing>,<thing>,...
  stop with error:    --refuse-<thing>,<thing>,... | --no-force-<thing>,...
 Forcing things:
  [!] all                Set all force options
  [*] downgrade          Replace a package with a lower version
...
  [!] remove-reinstreq   Remove packages which require installation
  [!] remove-essential   Remove an essential package

Comment: Running the nuclear option gives me this message: dpkg: error: need an action option

Comment: hmm, same message: error: need an action option

Comment: Fumbly fingers, sorry. Try `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post with the results